# A line on the left of divs appear when I transition them

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
    var numSquares = 6;
    var containerId = document.getElementById("container");
    var jumbotronId = document.getElementById("jumbotronId");
    var newGame = document.getElementById("newGame");
    var easyGame = document.getElementById("easyGame");
    var hardGame = document.getElementById("hardGame");
    var header = document.getElementById("header");
    var modeOfGame = document.getElementsByClassName("mode")

    var divData = document.getElementsByClassName("square");

    var ans = document.getElementsByClassName("dick");
    var head = document.getElementById("rgbHeader");
    var message = document.getElementById("message");

    var newGameButton = document.getElementById("newGame");

    var pickedColor;

    var colors;







    newBgColor();
    newPickedColor();



console.log(colors);


function generateRandomColor(num){

  var arr = [];

  for(i = 0; i < num; i++){

    arr.push(randomRGB());


  }

  return arr;

}

  
  for(i = 0; i < modeOfGame.length; i++){

    modeOfGame[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      modeOfGame[0].classList.remove("selected");
      modeOfGame[1].classList.remove("selected");
      this.classList.add("selected");

      this.textContent === "Easy" ? numSquares = 3 : numSquares = 6;

      newBgColor();





    });

  }
  

  






    function randomNum() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    }
    

    function randomRGB() {
      var color = "rgb(" + randomNum() + ", " + randomNum() + ", " + randomNum() + ")"

      return color;

      }



    function newBgColor(){

      header.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(70, 130, 180)";




       colors = generateRandomColor(numSquares);

        for(i = 0; i < divData.length; i++){


        if(colors[i]){
        divData[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
        divData[i].style.display = "block";

        }else{
          divData[i].style.display = "none";

        }



        }
        




      }



    function newPickedColor(){

      message.textContent = "";


      pickedColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]


      head.textContent = pickedColor;



    }





      newGame.addEventListener("click", function(){

      

       numSquares === 3 ? difficult = false : difficult = true;



        newBgColor(difficult);
        newPickedColor();




      });

  
      for(i = 0; i < modeOfGame.length; i++){


        modeOfGame[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
          modeOfGame[0].classList.remove("selected");
          modeOfGame[1].classList.remove("selected");
          this.classList.add("selected");

          this.textContent ==="Easy"? numSquares = 3 : numSquares = 6;

          newBgColor();
          newPickedColor();


        });

      }
      






 

      function changeColor(color){

        for(i = 0; i < divData.length; i++){

          if(divData[i].style.backgroundColor === color){

            continue
          }else{

            divData[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
          }


        }


      }






    









      for(i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){


      


      divData[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      
     var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;


      if(clickedColor === pickedColor){


        changeColor(clickedColor);

        header.style.backgroundColor = pickedColor;


        message.textContent = "Correct!"
        newGame.textContent = "Play Again?"
      }else{

        this.style.backgroundColor = "#232323";


        message.textContent = "Try Again!"
      }


      });



      }


      newGameButton.addEventListener("click", function(){

        this.textContent = "New Colors";


      });
```

```css
body{

 background-color: #232323;
 font-family: "Montserrat", "Avenir";
 margin: 0px;



}

#myNav{


 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 height: 30px;




}



#jumbotronId{


 height: 150px;

}






.square{
 

 width: 30%;
 padding-bottom: 25%; 
 margin: 1.66%;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 20%;
 transition: background-color 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s;




}

#container{
 margin: 20px auto;
 max-width: 600px;




}

#header{

 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 1.1;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 background-color: steelblue;
 margin: 0px auto;
 transition: background-color 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s;


}





#headerContainer{

 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 800px;

}


#message{

 display: inline-block;
 width: 20%;
}

button{

 border: none;
 background: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 height: 100%;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #4682b4;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-size: inherit;
 transition: background-color .3s, color .3s;
 -moz-transition: background-color .3s, color .3s;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .3s, color .3s;
}



button:hover{

 background-color: steelblue;
 color: white;
}

#rgbHeader{

 font-size: 200%;
}


.selected{

 background-color: steelblue;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>RGB Guessing Game</title>



 <script type="text/javascript" src = "rgb.js" async></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href = "rgb.css">

</head>
<body>


 
  
  <h1 id = "header">THE GREAT <br><span id = "rgbHeader">ddd</span><br> GUESSING GAME</h1>

  





<div id = "myNav">




  <button id = "newGame">New Color</button>






        <span id = "message"></span>

  

    
        <button class = "mode">Easy</button>
        <button class = "mode selected">Hard</button>






    

</div>


<div id = "container">



 


  <div id = "rgb0" class = "square"></div>
  <div id = "rgb1" class = "square"></div>
  <div id = "rgb2" class = "square"></div>

  <div id = "rgb3" class = "square"></div>
  <div id = "rgb4" class = "square"></div>
  <div id = "rgb5" class = "square"></div>




 



</div>










</body>
</html>
```

I have followed an online tutorial on how to make a RGB guessing game using HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I have encountered a problem wherein the div squares, specifically on the left part, don't seem to transition properly when I click on it. They leave random lines.

I have tried changing the padding property from the instructed "15%" into 20px and 2em and the lines seem to go away. But still, I'm curious why every time I use a percentage value, the squares leave lines.

Random lines shouldn't appear when I transition the squares.

The image link will show what happens when I click the squares on the left

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU3g5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the square is hidden, you use

```
this.style.backgroundColor = "#232323";
```

This can cause issues if there is a border set. Instead, use `opacity: 0;` which would be

```
this.style.opacity = "0";
```

Also, don't forget to update your CSS transitions:

```
transition: opacity 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
```

Finally, make sure you keep your code clean. Spacing it out that much makes it difficult for others to read. The example code has an been updated to include more compact spacing, which should help readability.

```js
var numSquares = 6;
var containerId = document.getElementById("container");
var jumbotronId = document.getElementById("jumbotronId");
var newGame = document.getElementById("newGame");
var easyGame = document.getElementById("easyGame");
var hardGame = document.getElementById("hardGame");
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var modeOfGame = document.getElementsByClassName("mode")

var divData = document.getElementsByClassName("square");

var ans = document.getElementsByClassName("dick");
var head = document.getElementById("rgbHeader");
var message = document.getElementById("message");

var newGameButton = document.getElementById("newGame");

var pickedColor;

var colors;


newBgColor();
newPickedColor();

console.log(colors);

function generateRandomColor(num) {
  var arr = [];
  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    arr.push(randomRGB());
  }
  return arr;
}
for (i = 0; i < modeOfGame.length; i++) {
  modeOfGame[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    modeOfGame[0].classList.remove("selected");
    modeOfGame[1].classList.remove("selected");
    this.classList.add("selected");
    this.textContent === "Easy" ? numSquares = 3 : numSquares = 6;
    newBgColor();
  });
}

function randomNum() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}

function randomRGB() {
  var color = "rgb(" + randomNum() + ", " + randomNum() + ", " + randomNum() + ")"
  return color;
}

function newBgColor() {
  header.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(70, 130, 180)";
  colors = generateRandomColor(numSquares);
  for (i = 0; i < divData.length; i++) {
    if (colors[i]) {
      divData[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
      divData[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      divData[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

function newPickedColor() {
  message.textContent = "";
  pickedColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
  head.textContent = pickedColor;
}
newGame.addEventListener("click", function() {
  numSquares === 3 ? difficult = false : difficult = true;
  newBgColor(difficult);
  newPickedColor();
});
for (i = 0; i < modeOfGame.length; i++) {
  modeOfGame[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    modeOfGame[0].classList.remove("selected");
    modeOfGame[1].classList.remove("selected");
    this.classList.add("selected");
    this.textContent === "Easy" ? numSquares = 3 : numSquares = 6;
    newBgColor();
    newPickedColor();
  });
}

function changeColor(color) {
  for (i = 0; i < divData.length; i++) {
    if (divData[i].style.backgroundColor === color) {
      continue
    } else {
      divData[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
  }
}
for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  divData[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
    if (clickedColor === pickedColor) {
      changeColor(clickedColor);
      header.style.backgroundColor = pickedColor;
      message.textContent = "Correct!"
      newGame.textContent = "Play Again?"
    } else {
      this.style.opacity = "0";
      message.textContent = "Try Again!"
    }
  });
}
newGameButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.textContent = "New Colors";
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #232323;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Avenir";
  margin: 0px;
}

#myNav {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
}

#jumbotronId {
  height: 150px;
}

.square {
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  margin: 1.66%;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 20%;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

#container {
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.1;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: steelblue;
  margin: 0px auto;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

#headerContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

#message {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #4682b4;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: inherit;
  transition: background-color .3s, color .3s;
  -moz-transition: background-color .3s, color .3s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s, color .3s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: white;
}

#rgbHeader {
  font-size: 200%;
}

.selected {
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>RGB Guessing Game</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="rgb.js" async></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="rgb.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="header">THE GREAT <br><span id="rgbHeader">ddd</span><br> GUESSING GAME</h1>
  <div id="myNav">
    <button id="newGame">New Color</button>
    <span id="message"></span>
    <button class="mode">Easy</button>
    <button class="mode selected">Hard</button>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="rgb0" class="square"></div>
    <div id="rgb1" class="square"></div>
    <div id="rgb2" class="square"></div>
    <div id="rgb3" class="square"></div>
    <div id="rgb4" class="square"></div>
    <div id="rgb5" class="square"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @devision1088! You were right, I thought the problem was with my border-radius. I tried not using 20% and went with 2em/20px and the lines didn't appear but I had no idea why. I agree with the spacing as well. It absolutely looks better when spaced like your answer.